# how to animate a view just like vehicle info view in Uber App?

Tags: ios, objective-c, animation, uiviewanimation, uiviewanimationtransition

I want to implement a view animation in my iOS app (objective c) just like the animation which occurs when we try to open uber vehicle info view(see screenshot). I have searched some view animation but didn't get the result as per my expectations.

[image]

Comment: Add GIF of animation which you want to implement

Comment: Yes I checked. but if you add GIF then its easy for other developer to understand that which animation you want.

Comment: @JD.okay will do it